# How to fix network after mistake with aircrack-ng in Kali Linux?

Tags: networking, kali-linux, airodump-ng

I typed: `airodump-ng eth0` then I know it is my mistake. it token my network on Kali Linux VirtualBox. After mistake, I can't access my network. When I typed `ifconfig` (as root), it got this response:

```
# ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2222  bytes 176585 (172.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2222  bytes 176585 (172.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

# eth0 start
bash: eth0: command not found

#
```

<sup>[manually transcribed from [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu9r9.png)]</sup>

How can I fix this mistake?

Comment: please avoid pasting picture, where text would do !

Comment: Can you provide output from "ip link"

Comment: Why `eth0 start` ? eth0 is not a command, it's a network interface name.

Answer (score 1):

Using `eth0 start` won't work because `eth0` isn't a command.

Use `ip link set dev eth0 up` instead, to bring up the interface.

If you need to assign an address to the interface use `ip a add 192.168.1.200/24 dev eth0`

Answer (score 1):

You might need to delete the monitor interface created by `aircrack-ng`.

For example, my original interface was `wlp1s0`, and the monitor interface it created was `wlan0mon`

```
iw dev wlan0mon del
iw phy phy0 interface add wlp1s0 type managed
```

When it's switched back to managed mode, that lets things like NetworkManager use it again.

https://superuser.com/questions/242358/removing-wlan0mon-created-by-kismet

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After messing around with `airmon-ng` I couldn't connect to any networks. Even the network manager icon disappeared from the taskbar (KDE). If I checked `iwconfig`, I would see `eth0`, `lo`, and `wlan0mon` instead of just `wlan0`. Doing:

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

just told me no such device exists. That clued me into how to potentially fix the mode.

Here are the commands that restored my Internet access:

First, restart your network manager:

```
 service NetworkManager restart
```

(Your network manager service might be called `Network-Manager`.)

Let's see what your wireless adapter is doing:

```
 iwconfig
```

(It might be called something like `wlan0mon` instead of `wlan0`,
indicating it is still in monitor mode.)

Since it is still in monitor mode, let's turn the normal mode back on:

```
 airmon-ng start wlan0 7
```

(The last number is the channel and can probably be omitted.)

Now let's stop the monitoring interface:

```
 airmon-ng stop wlan0mon
```

And finally, let's turn your normal network adapter back on:

```
 ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Check for the normal adapter now:

```
 ifconfig
```

(Should no longer show the "mon" equivalent and instead show `wlan0` or whatever your adapter is called in normal mode.)

Now you can use your network manager app to reconnect to the network for browsing.

Not sure why I haven't seen this solution. Most end up rebooting to get back to normal Internet mode.

Comment: I’m not sure whether this really answers the question; the OP is trying to get ``eth0`` working again.

Answer (score -2):

There should be super domain permission required to run airmon-ng. So try:

```
sudo airmon-ng eth0 start
```

Comment: Unless the OP was being deliberately misleading, they seem to already be running as root.